401 Unauthorized with Devise basic auth
I made a Rails install 7.2.1, installed Devise basic. I set in my applications controller:
  def after_sign_in_path_for(current_user)
    # Assuming 'Dashboard' is a model and you have a show action
    dashboard_path(current_user)
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(current_user)
    # Assuming 'Dashboard' is a model and you have a show action
    dashboard_path(current_user)
  end 

creds are valid, no error on that, but everything I try causes the 401 unauthorized error I keep getting and I have no idea why:
App 8384 output: I, [2024-09-20T22:12:03.793655 #8384]  INFO -- : [58b545d7-4177-4864-8459-3ddd062477a7] Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 173.171.196.191 at 2024-09-20 22:12:03 +0000
App 8384 output: I, [2024-09-20T22:12:03.794580 #8384]  INFO -- : [58b545d7-4177-4864-8459-3ddd062477a7] Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
App 8384 output: I, [2024-09-20T22:12:03.794622 #8384]  INFO -- : [58b545d7-4177-4864-8459-3ddd062477a7]   Parameters: {"email"=>"mhenry1228@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0", "commit"=>"Log in"}
App 8384 output: I, [2024-09-20T22:12:03.795139 #8384]  INFO -- : [58b545d7-4177-4864-8459-3ddd062477a7] CSRF Protection Enabled? false
App 8384 output: I, [2024-09-20T22:12:03.795444 #8384]  INFO -- : [58b545d7-4177-4864-8459-3ddd062477a7] Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms (0 queries, 0 cached) | GC: 0.0ms)
App 8384 output: I, [2024-09-20T22:12:03.796212 #8384]  INFO -- : [58b545d7-4177-4864-8459-3ddd062477a7] Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as TURBO_STREAM
App 8384 output: I, [2024-09-20T22:12:03.796252 #8384]  INFO -- : [58b545d7-4177-4864-8459-3ddd062477a7]   Parameters: {"email"=>"mhenry1228@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0", "commit"=>"Log in"}
App 8384 output: I, [2024-09-20T22:12:03.796357 #8384]  INFO -- : [58b545d7-4177-4864-8459-3ddd062477a7] CSRF Protection Enabled? false
App 8384 output: I, [2024-09-20T22:12:03.798636 #8384]  INFO -- : [58b545d7-4177-4864-8459-3ddd062477a7]   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 1.5ms | GC: 0.1ms)
App 8384 output: I, [2024-09-20T22:12:03.798781 #8384]  INFO -- : [58b545d7-4177-4864-8459-3ddd062477a7] Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms (0 queries, 0 cached) | GC: 0.1ms)


There’s not a lot to go on here.

@DaveNewton that's the point.. all I did was install devise, and set it up after sign_in to redirect to a path I want. Creds perfectly fine, but it will not go pass the log in screen and give me 401. If I did a bunch of custom work I would of added it, but I didn't do much past what I posted here and it's still not working. I even did a test app where all I did was add devise and no other tables and it's all good until devise comes in to play.

Is the login route a protected route?

@DaveNewton I don't know what you mean...if that was something I had to create then I would venture to say no...the login route is devise.

If you get a 401 unauth hitting the logging page wouldn’t that imply it’s being protected?

@DaveNewton I would have to guess so then.

Basic authentication is the browsers built in authentication using the Authorization: Basic <credentials> headers and most likely has nothing to do with your question.  What you're using is actually just called session based authentication. I'm also fairly certain that the core issue is  whatever is in your Users::SessionsController and not the Devise gem.

Your logs say CSRF Protection Enabled? false
Rails uses CSRF tokens to prevent unauthorized actions and when CSRF protection is disabled, the server may block sign-in attempts which might be why you are getting a 401.
I would make sure the CSRF Protection is enabled:
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end

A good reference might be https://codeql.github.com/codeql-query-help/ruby/rb-csrf-protection-not-enabled/

I agree with you there, but when I tried(before I posted my question) protect_from_forgery with: :exception that gave me csrf errors, so I feel like I'm stuck between a unauthorized rock and a csrf hard place.

After much trying, and getting nowhere I found this solution of downgrading my rack version and it solved my auth problem.
